# Using ExtJS and Java with Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, extjs, jfreechart

My task is to write a Java based web application which will produce various charts like WaferMap, Histogram, Overlay Chart etc.

The front end is ExtJS and the chart generation part is taken care by JFreeChart.
The data for charts will be in multiple .CSV files which are stored in the file system.

My questions are:

1. The .CSV files size will be in GB's. Can I store these files in HDFS and query them during run-time and display data in frontend?
2. Is using Hadoop ecosystem  is a feasible solution for my above requirement?  Should I also consider Apache pig or hive for querying the CSV file?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes you can (Apache Hive)
2. It all depends but Hive seems like what you're looking for. It was designed with a SQL like feel and can include SQL clauses. It is widely used with major corps like Facebook, Netflix, FINRA, etc. In your case, supporting SQL syntax also means that you can integrate with Java's JDBC driver real easy and query data from your CSV files.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/

Setting up Hive can be a bit difficult at first if you're not too familiar with the Hadoop environment. The above link is a great reference link to understand Hive better and get you in the right direction.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Yes. I am exploring now to Integrate Hive and Java front end

Comment: Let me know any hiccups you come across and I'll try and help best I can. Good luck!